# Bootable usb not working

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop with a new hard drive and no current operating system, i have went through the process of creating a bootable usb disk using ISO to USB, but when i plug it into my laptop and change the BIOS to boot from usb, it goes to a black screen with a blinking cursor in the top left hand corner.

Comment: Did you use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create the bootable USB?

Answer (score 0):

Try another usb stick. I've had lots of strange experiences with some usb thumbdrives only working with some mb/firmware combinations.